# I have a problem with spring boot inheritance classes

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, inheritance

I have a user class which is a supper class and a student class a subclass of users. I don’t have an error in the code but I don't why it does not make tables in the database when I remove "extends user" it creates the table?

**here is my code**

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Data
public abstract class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length = 20)
    private Role name;
} 

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@Data
public class Student  extends User{
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private LocalDate dob;
    private String tell;
    private String course;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [link](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance) you can have an overview of the following approaches to inheritance:

1. `MappedSuperclass` - the parent classes, can't be entities
2. `Single Table` -The entities from different classes with a common ancestor are placed in a single table.
3. `Joined Table` - Each class has its table, and querying a subclass entity requires joining the tables.
4. `Table per Class` -All the properties of a class are in its table, so no join is required.

Regards

Comment: thank you for your response, but I already solved it :)

Comment: I thought so :) but it could maybe be helpful for others. Cheers!